# What to do if Java program should continuously receive data from serial comm, but now experiencing delay or lag on the program?

Tags: java, timer, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

I am using Arduino connected to Java Netbeans through Serialcomm. My java program should continuously receive data and the Serial Port must continuously be open. And I am now experiencing delay or lag on the program. I am thinking that it may be because of the timer, so I tried to remove it. But the serial port is not opening anymore when I do that.

What should I do to remove the lag or the program being slowed?
Maybe if there's another way of doing this, like changing my action listener or another way for it to read the serial port continuously without using a timer.

Thank you in advance for answering!

```
Timer timer ;   
ActionListener readRF = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String str;
 SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
//In the constructor pass the name of the port with which we work

try {
    //Open port
    serialPort.openPort();

    
    serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);



    Thread.sleep(1000);//Very important !!!



    //Read data from port
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        str = serialPort.readString();
        

        if (str != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            if(str.contains("15538849")){
            queue1.setText(String.valueOf(q.Table1Peek()));
            }else if(str.contains("15538850")){
            q.Table1DeQueue();    
            queue1.setText(String.valueOf(q.Table1Peek()));
            }
        }

        Thread.sleep(100);
    }

    //Closing the port
    serialPort.closePort();

} catch (SerialPortException ex ) {
    System.out.println(ex);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
        }

};
                timer = new Timer(1000,readRF);
                timer.setInitialDelay(0);
                timer.start();
```